# Does these conditions ensure Hardy space membership?

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let D be a disk of center $c$ and radius $R>0$ located in the complex plane, $\partial D$ be the boundary of the disk, $H(D)$ denote the collection of analytic functions defined on $D$, $$H^p(D)=\left\{f\in H(D):\exists C>0,\sup_{r\in[0,R)}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(c+re^{i\theta})|^pd\theta\leq C<\infty\right\},\quad 0<p<\infty.$$
Now, I want to prove that a function with the following properties belongs to $H^p(D)$.
Let $F\in H(D)$ that can be analytically extended on $\partial D$ except for a finite number of points on $\partial D=\{c+Re^{i\theta}:\theta\in[0,2\pi)\}$ (and thus on neighborhoods of those points that carry $F$ analytically in the outer of $D$) where we don't know how $F$ behaves. But we do know that the following integral is bounded $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(c+Re^{i\theta}|^pd\theta\leq C,$$
for some $0<p<1$.
My question is if these conditions are enough to ensure that $F\in H^p(D)$ for the same $0<p<1$.

Of course, the problem is with these points on $\partial D$, which I cannot extend $F$, otherwise, it would be in $H^p(D)$, trivially.

Comment: you need an extra condition (usually expressed in terms of the Nevanlinna spaces, so $\lim_{r \to 1}\int_0^{2\pi} \log^+f(re^{it})dt=\int_0^{2\pi} \log^+f(e^{it})dt$ - should look up a book on Hardy spaces like Duren say for details; for example the usual counterexample, $e^{\frac{z+1}{1-z}}$ is analytic in the plane except at $1$, bounded on the unit circle so in any $L^p(dt)$ (of the unit circle) but it is not in any $H^p(D)$ of the unit disc as it is easily seen since it is highly unbounded there

Comment: @Conrad I see. Since you answered, I have another question regarding Hardy spaces. If $F$ is the Cauchy integral of an $L^1$ function of the unit circle, is it true that $F$ is in the $H^p$ for every $0<p<1$?

Comment: yes the result is true since one can decompose any integrable circle function $f=u_{+}-u_{-}+i(v_{+}-v_{-})$ where all those are nonnegative (and integrable - eg $u_{+}=\max (f,0)$) and it is easy to see that the Cauchy transform of a nonnegative function has positive real part and those are in $H^p, 0<p<1$ by Littlewood subordination theorem as $\Re G>0$ implies (pretty much by definition) $G/G(0)$ is subordinate to $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$